# SFML Audio.h file giving many errors when linking

Tags: c++, sfml

When I link my program, I get many errors in my output. This only happens after I add the audio.h file. This is my output directory. Sorry if its long or unreadable I dont know what else to show.

```
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(Sound.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alSourcef referenced in function "public: void __thiscall sf::Sound::setPlayingOffset(class sf::Time)" (?setPlayingOffset@Sound@sf@@QAEXVTime@2@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundSource.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__alSourcef
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(Sound.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alSourcei referenced in function "public: void __thiscall sf::Sound::setBuffer(class sf::SoundBuffer const &)" (?setBuffer@Sound@sf@@QAEXABVSoundBuffer@2@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundSource.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__alSourcei
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(Sound.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGetSourcef referenced in function "public: class sf::Time __thiscall sf::Sound::getPlayingOffset(void)const " (?getPlayingOffset@Sound@sf@@QBE?AVTime@2@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundSource.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGetSourcef
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(Sound.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGetSourcei referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall sf::Sound::getLoop(void)const " (?getLoop@Sound@sf@@QBE_NXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundSource.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGetSourcei
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(Sound.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alSourcePlay referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall sf::Sound::play(void)" (?play@Sound@sf@@UAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(Sound.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alSourceStop referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall sf::Sound::stop(void)" (?stop@Sound@sf@@UAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(Sound.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alSourcePause referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall sf::Sound::pause(void)" (?pause@Sound@sf@@UAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundBuffer.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGenBuffers referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::SoundBuffer::SoundBuffer(void)" (??0SoundBuffer@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundBuffer.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alDeleteBuffers referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::SoundBuffer::~SoundBuffer(void)" (??1SoundBuffer@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundBuffer.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alBufferData referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall sf::SoundBuffer::update(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?update@SoundBuffer@sf@@AAE_NII@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundBuffer.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGetBufferi referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall sf::SoundBuffer::getSampleRate(void)const " (?getSampleRate@SoundBuffer@sf@@QBEIXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundSource.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGenSources referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::SoundSource::SoundSource(class sf::SoundSource const &)" (??0SoundSource@sf@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundSource.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alDeleteSources referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall sf::SoundSource::~SoundSource(void)" (??1SoundSource@sf@@UAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundSource.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alSource3f referenced in function "public: void __thiscall sf::SoundSource::setPosition(float,float,float)" (?setPosition@SoundSource@sf@@QAEXMMM@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundSource.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGetSource3f referenced in function "public: class sf::Vector3<float> __thiscall sf::SoundSource::getPosition(void)const " (?getPosition@SoundSource@sf@@QBE?AV?$Vector3@M@2@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(ALCheck.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGetError referenced in function "void __cdecl sf::priv::alCheckError(char const *,unsigned int,char const *)" (?alCheckError@priv@sf@@YAXPBDI0@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alIsExtensionPresent referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::AudioDevice::isExtensionSupported(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?isExtensionSupported@AudioDevice@priv@sf@@SA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alGetEnumValue referenced in function "public: static int __cdecl sf::priv::AudioDevice::getFormatFromChannelCount(unsigned int)" (?getFormatFromChannelCount@AudioDevice@priv@sf@@SAHI@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alListenerf referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::priv::AudioDevice::AudioDevice(void)" (??0AudioDevice@priv@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alListener3f referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::priv::AudioDevice::AudioDevice(void)" (??0AudioDevice@priv@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alListenerfv referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::priv::AudioDevice::AudioDevice(void)" (??0AudioDevice@priv@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alcCreateContext referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::priv::AudioDevice::AudioDevice(void)" (??0AudioDevice@priv@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alcMakeContextCurrent referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::priv::AudioDevice::AudioDevice(void)" (??0AudioDevice@priv@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alcDestroyContext referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::priv::AudioDevice::~AudioDevice(void)" (??1AudioDevice@priv@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alcOpenDevice referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::priv::AudioDevice::AudioDevice(void)" (??0AudioDevice@priv@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alcCloseDevice referenced in function "public: __thiscall sf::priv::AudioDevice::~AudioDevice(void)" (??1AudioDevice@priv@sf@@QAE@XZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(AudioDevice.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__alcIsExtensionPresent referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::AudioDevice::isExtensionSupported(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?isExtensionSupported@AudioDevice@priv@sf@@SA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_decoder_new referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::SoundFileReaderFlac::check(class sf::InputStream &)" (?check@SoundFileReaderFlac@priv@sf@@SA_NAAVInputStream@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_decoder_delete referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::SoundFileReaderFlac::check(class sf::InputStream &)" (?check@SoundFileReaderFlac@priv@sf@@SA_NAAVInputStream@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_decoder_get_state referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned __int64 __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileReaderFlac::read(short *,unsigned __int64)" (?read@SoundFileReaderFlac@priv@sf@@UAE_KPAF_K@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_decoder_init_stream referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::SoundFileReaderFlac::check(class sf::InputStream &)" (?check@SoundFileReaderFlac@priv@sf@@SA_NAAVInputStream@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_decoder_finish referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::SoundFileReaderFlac::check(class sf::InputStream &)" (?check@SoundFileReaderFlac@priv@sf@@SA_NAAVInputStream@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_decoder_process_single referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned __int64 __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileReaderFlac::read(short *,unsigned __int64)" (?read@SoundFileReaderFlac@priv@sf@@UAE_KPAF_K@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_decoder_process_until_end_of_metadata referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::SoundFileReaderFlac::check(class sf::InputStream &)" (?check@SoundFileReaderFlac@priv@sf@@SA_NAAVInputStream@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_decoder_skip_single_frame referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileReaderFlac::seek(unsigned __int64)" (?seek@SoundFileReaderFlac@priv@sf@@UAEX_K@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_decoder_seek_absolute referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileReaderFlac::seek(unsigned __int64)" (?seek@SoundFileReaderFlac@priv@sf@@UAEX_K@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_encoder_new referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterFlac::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterFlac@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_encoder_delete referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterFlac::close(void)" (?close@SoundFileWriterFlac@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_encoder_set_channels referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterFlac::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterFlac@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_encoder_set_bits_per_sample referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterFlac::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterFlac@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_encoder_set_sample_rate referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterFlac::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterFlac@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_encoder_init_file referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterFlac::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterFlac@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_encoder_finish referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterFlac::close(void)" (?close@SoundFileWriterFlac@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterFlac.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterFlac::write(short const *,unsigned __int64)" (?write@SoundFileWriterFlac@priv@sf@@UAEXPBF_K@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ov_clear referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::SoundFileReaderOgg::check(class sf::InputStream &)" (?check@SoundFileReaderOgg@priv@sf@@SA_NAAVInputStream@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ov_open_callbacks referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileReaderOgg::open(class sf::InputStream &,struct sf::SoundFileReader::Info &)" (?open@SoundFileReaderOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NAAVInputStream@3@AAUInfo@SoundFileReader@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ov_test_callbacks referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl sf::priv::SoundFileReaderOgg::check(class sf::InputStream &)" (?check@SoundFileReaderOgg@priv@sf@@SA_NAAVInputStream@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ov_pcm_total referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileReaderOgg::open(class sf::InputStream &,struct sf::SoundFileReader::Info &)" (?open@SoundFileReaderOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NAAVInputStream@3@AAUInfo@SoundFileReader@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ov_pcm_seek referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileReaderOgg::seek(unsigned __int64)" (?seek@SoundFileReaderOgg@priv@sf@@UAEX_K@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ov_info referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileReaderOgg::open(class sf::InputStream &,struct sf::SoundFileReader::Info &)" (?open@SoundFileReaderOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NAAVInputStream@3@AAUInfo@SoundFileReader@3@@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileReaderOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ov_read referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned __int64 __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileReaderOgg::read(short *,unsigned __int64)" (?read@SoundFileReaderOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_KPAF_K@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ogg_stream_packetin referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ogg_stream_flush referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ogg_stream_init referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ogg_stream_clear referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::close(void)" (?close@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_info_init referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_info_clear referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::close(void)" (?close@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_comment_init referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_comment_clear referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_block_init referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::flushBlocks(void)" (?flushBlocks@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_block_clear referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::flushBlocks(void)" (?flushBlocks@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_dsp_clear referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::close(void)" (?close@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_analysis_init referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_analysis_headerout referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?open@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@II@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_analysis_buffer referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::write(short const *,unsigned __int64)" (?write@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAEXPBF_K@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_analysis_wrote referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::write(short const *,unsigned __int64)" (?write@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@UAEXPBF_K@Z)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_analysis_blockout referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::flushBlocks(void)" (?flushBlocks@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_analysis referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::flushBlocks(void)" (?flushBlocks@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_bitrate_addblock referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::flushBlocks(void)" (?flushBlocks@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_bitrate_flushpacket referenced in function "private: void __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::flushBlocks(void)" (?flushBlocks@SoundFileWriterOgg@priv@sf@@AAEXXZ)
1>sfml-audio-s-d.lib(SoundFileWriterOgg.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vorbis_encode_init_vbr referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall sf::priv::SoundFileWriterOgg::open(class std::basic_st
```

Comment: It seems like you're building with a static library of SFML. A static library is nothing more than a collection of object files, and linking with such a library is basically the same as linking with the individual object files. This means you need to explicitly link with *all* dependencies of the library as well (and their dependencies in turn, if they also are static libraries).

Comment: So what files would I need to link?

Comment: I haven't used SFML much these days, but I remember SFML` used `.hpp` files. Are you sure you're including `.hpp` files and not `.h` files?

Comment: I'm using .hpp files.

Comment: I included files and it worked, but now I'm getting "The code execution cannot proceed because OpenAl3s.dll was not found.

Comment: I fixed my issue. I had to add these in my addition dependencies; openal32.lib
flac.lib
vorbisenc.lib
vorbisfile.lib
vorbis.lib
ogg.lib     I then added openal32.lib
flac.lib
vorbisenc.lib
vorbisfile.lib
vorbis.lib
ogg.lib    I then add OpenAll32.dll from the bin folder in my SFML install folder.